# Finding Minimum value in row of multiple columns using SQL

Tags: sql, minimum

I'm trying to find the minimum value for an ID (row) out of 6 columns of values.  I first have to query from a table that has string values like 'partial complete', null values, missing strings which I set to a numeric value matching that step's sequence (step1,step2,step3.step4,step5,step6).  Otherwise I set it to zero and i don't care about zero's when calculating the minimum value.

So I thought i could use a case statement to go through and calculate the minimum value but I'm not getting that consistently.  Below is my code so if there are better solutions or changes I need to make, please let me know.  Thank you in advance!  Sorry I didn't format this correctly

```
Select pt.PROJECT_NUMBER, pt.STEP1, pt.STEP2, pt.STEP3, pt.STEP4, pt.STEP5, pt.STEP6,
CASE WHEN STEP1 = 'PARTIAL COMPLETE' OR STEP1 IS NULL OR STEP1 = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS step1_val,
CASE WHEN STEP2 = 'PARTIAL COMPLETE' OR STEP2 IS NULL OR STEP2 = '' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END AS step2_val,
CASE WHEN STEP3 = 'PARTIAL COMPLETE' OR STEP3 IS NULL OR STEP3 = '' THEN 3 ELSE 0 END AS step3_val,
CASE WHEN STEP4 = 'PARTIAL COMPLETE' OR STEP4 IS NULL OR STEP4 = '' THEN 4 ELSE 0 END AS step4_val,
CASE WHEN STEP5 = 'PARTIAL COMPLETE' OR STEP5 IS NULL OR STEP5 = '' THEN 5 ELSE 0 END AS step5_val,
CASE WHEN STEP6 = 'PARTIAL COMPLETE' OR STEP6 IS NULL OR STEP6 = '' THEN 6 ELSE 0 END AS step6_val


INTO #Temp

FROM
ProjectTracker.GIS.PROJECT_TRACKING pt 
WHERE PROJECT_RECEIVED = 'YES' AND PROJECT_NUMBER = '5797'


SELECT * FROM #Temp


Select PROJECT_NUMBER,
        Case When step1_val < step2_val And step1_val < step3_val And step1_val < step4_val And step1_val < step5_val And step1_val < step6_val Then step1_val
            When step2_val < step1_val And step2_val < step3_val And step2_val < step4_val And step2_val < step5_val And step2_val < step6_val Then step2_val
            When step3_val < step1_val And step3_val < step2_val And step3_val < step4_val And step3_val < step5_val And step3_val < step6_val Then step3_val
            When step4_val < step1_val And step4_val < step2_val And step4_val < step3_val And step4_val < step5_val And step4_val < step6_val Then step4_val
            When step5_val < step1_val And step5_val < step2_val And step5_val < step3_val And step5_val  < step4_val And step5_val < step6_val Then step5_val
            Else step6_val
            End As TheMin
From   #Temp

Drop Table #Temp
```

---

This produces the results in image, obviously the expected result should be 5 so I'm not sure where I went wrong

[image]

Comment: This table design is a nightmare. What happens if you will have one more step in the future? You have to redesign all. Please read this article carefully 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization
and redesign your database before it is too late ;)

Comment: @Claus- thanks for your kind words.  I asked a very basic question and was hoping for some help rather than a lecture on how terrible i am at sql.  thank you though

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work:

```
Select pt.PROJECT_NUMBER, pt.STEP1, pt.STEP2, pt.STEP3, pt.STEP4, pt.STEP5, pt.STEP6,
```

CASE WHEN STEP1 = 'PARTIAL COMPLETE' OR STEP1 IS NULL OR STEP1 = '' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS step1_val,
CASE WHEN STEP2 = 'PARTIAL COMPLETE' OR STEP2 IS NULL OR STEP2 = '' THEN 2 ELSE NULL END AS step2_val,
CASE WHEN STEP3 = 'PARTIAL COMPLETE' OR STEP3 IS NULL OR STEP3 = '' THEN 3 ELSE NULL END AS step3_val,
CASE WHEN STEP4 = 'PARTIAL COMPLETE' OR STEP4 IS NULL OR STEP4 = '' THEN 4 ELSE NULL END AS step4_val,
CASE WHEN STEP5 = 'PARTIAL COMPLETE' OR STEP5 IS NULL OR STEP5 = '' THEN 5 ELSE NULL END AS step5_val,
CASE WHEN STEP6 = 'PARTIAL COMPLETE' OR STEP6 IS NULL OR STEP6 = '' THEN 6 ELSE NULL END AS step6_val

INTO #Temp

FROM
ProjectTracker.GIS.PROJECT_TRACKING pt
WHERE PROJECT_RECEIVED = 'YES' --AND PROJECT_NUMBER = '11782'

SELECT * FROM #Temp

SELECT PROJECT_NUMBER,MIN(x.a)
FROM
(
SELECT PROJECT_NUMBER,step1_val a FROM #Temp
UNION
SELECT PROJECT_NUMBER,step2_val a FROM #Temp
UNION
SELECT PROJECT_NUMBER,step3_val a FROM #Temp
UNION
SELECT PROJECT_NUMBER,step4_val a FROM #Temp
UNION
SELECT PROJECT_NUMBER,step5_val a FROM #Temp
UNION
SELECT PROJECT_NUMBER,step6_val a FROM #Temp
) x
GROUP BY PROJECT_NUMBER

Drop Table #Temp